# Search and replace inside a file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have an XML file that contains thousands of lines, and occasionally a closing tag is left out. This is problematic because I've got a python script that's taking it and turning it into a spreadsheet, but when the closing tag is missing the script breaks and sends incomplete data.

Here's an example of the XML:

```
<notes>
    <note>
        <note>-Some text
            <date>2014-07-30T14:30:18-07:00</date>
    </note>
</notes>
```

Can anyone tell me how to search inside the file, find the places where there's a missing  tag, and then insert it?

I've been trying to use grep, but I can't get it to find a set of strings on multiple lines. This is what I've been trying:

```
grep "'</date>'\n''</note>'\n'</notes>'" somefile.xml
```

Once the find problem is solved, I'm not sure how to go about replacing the text.

Comment: problem with finding the closing tag is not knowing where to insert it... You can have nested elements.  A possible solution is to have a XML schema so you can validate the XML prior to parsing

Comment: So should there always be two </note> tags before a </notes> tag?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, there should always be two </note> tags

Comment: Additionally, find out who's breaking your xml file and spank him severely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with the given data. It doesn't attempt to maintain spacing, however.

```
awk '
  /<note>/    { n++ }
  /<\/note>/  { n-- }
  /<\/notes>/ { for( ; n; n--) print"</note>" }
  { print }
' file
```

If it's always the inner one that's sometimes missing and it's always spaced the same, you could maintain spacing like this:

```
awk '
/^        <\/note>/          { endfound=1 }
/^    <\/note>/ && !endfound { print "        </note>" }
{ print; endfound=0 }
' file
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Purely for my benefit, can you explain the code so that I can adapt it and apply it later in life?

Comment: @eBooks_Nashville `n` automatically starts off at `0`. *Line 1:* if the line contains `<note>`, increment `n`. *Line 2*: if the line contains `</note>`, decrement `n`. *Line 3:* if line contains `</notes>`, then loop while `n` is not `0`, printing `</note>` and decrementing `n`. This prints any number of missing end tags and also resets `n` to `0`. *Line 4:* unconditionally print the current line.

Comment: @eBooks_Nashville If you're asking about how `awk` works in general, you could read the [GNU awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started)

Comment: Thanks! I was really just wondering exactly what your script was doing. I've got the man page for awk